# Casting Decimal with fr Locale

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I've extended the `DecimalPipe` and using it for the `fr` locale.

```
import { DecimalPipe, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDecimalPipe'
})
export class MyDecimalPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value: any, args?: any) : any {
        let result;

        registerLocaleData(localeFr);

        result = super.transform(value, args, 'fr');

        return result;
    }
}
```

Intially when the model binds it is visually displaying the decimal value accordingly to the format.

for e.g.  `23.00` is displayed as `23,00`but on editing and when it assigns back it is throwing the error

> core.js:6185 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '23,23 is not a number'
>   for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Usage:

```
constructor(private decimalPipe: MyDecimalPipe){}

update()
{
    this.decimalPipe.transform(model.value) //model.value is 23,23
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: the `implements PipeTransform` is unnecessary, because the `DecimalPipe` already implements it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for e.g. 23.00 is displayed as 23,00. but on editing and when it assigns
>   back it is throwing the error

In other words, when you use the `DecimalPipe` by string interpolation: `{{23.03 | myDecimalPipe}}` it works and prints `23,03`, why? because `23.03` value is a valid number that passes this angular method:

```
function strToNumber(value) {
    // Convert strings to numbers
    if (typeof value === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(value) - parseFloat(value))) {
        return Number(value);
    }
    if (typeof value !== 'number') {
        throw new Error(value + " is not a number");
    }
    return value;
}
```

When you programmatically calls the `transform` method you will have to use a valid number.

```
console.log(this.decimalPipe.transform("32.23")); // Will print 32,23
console.log(this.decimalPipe.transform("32,23")); // Throws error
```

To solve the issue you can simply convert the string `"32,23"` to a valid number using:

```
update()
{
    this.decimalPipe.transform(Number(model.value.replace(',', '.'));
}
```